Number of possible ordered quadruplets $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ such that $\max\{{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}}\}=5$, $\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}=1$

Number of possible ordered quadruplets $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ such that $\max\{{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}}\}=5$ and $\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}=1$ where $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

My solution:
I made all the cases possible
$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}&a_{2}&a_3&a_4& \text{permutation}\\1&1&1&5&\dfrac{4!}{3!}=4\\1&1&2&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&2&2&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&2&3&5&4!=24\\1&3&3&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&3&4&5& 4!=24\\1&4&4&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&4&5&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&5&5&5& \dfrac{4!}{3!}=4\\1&1&3&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&1&4&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&1&5&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}=6\\1&2&4&5&4!=24\\1&2&5&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\\1&3&5&5&\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12\end{bmatrix}$
Hence there are total of $194$ possible $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ But given answer is $52$?
Also is there general method for this without these many cases?

@CalvinLin Thanks, and edited

Hint: recall that if $ a_i \in{ 1, 2, \ldots n }$, then the number of $ (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) $ with $ max (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) = k$ is obtain by finding "Max is $\leq k$ - Max is $\leq k-1$" which is equal to $k^4 - (k-1)^4$.   Use this idea repeatedly. $\quad$ FWIW I get 194 ways.

If you really want to count directly, it would probably be simpler to index by how many of them are $1$ and how many of them are $5$.  This allows you to identify signatures like $(1,2,5,5)$ and $(1,3,5,5)$

@CalvinLin Thanks,

Disclaimer: I did a search and couldn't find a duplicate for this, but also recognize that it's hard to describe it  in search terms. The ideas here aren't novel, so I will delete this solution as needed.
First, recall that if $ a_i \in\{ 1, 2, \ldots n \}$, then the number of $ (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) $ with $ \max (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) = k \leq n $ is obtained by

Max is $k$ = Max is $\leq k$ - Max is $\leq k-1$,

and thus we have $k^4 - (k-1)^4$ ways.
Using that idea, show that

Max is 5 and Min is $ \geq 1$ is $5^4 - 4^4$ ways.
Max is 5 and Min is $ \geq 2$ is $4^4 - 3^4 $ ways.

If this is non-obvious, consider "Max is 4 and Min is $\geq 1$".


Hence, Max is 5 and Min is 1 is $(5^4 -4^4) - (4^4 - 3^4)$ = 194 ways.

Now generalize this to finding "$k$ variables, Max is $a$, Min is $b$".

We can view this as $|{1,2,3,4,5}^4|-|{1,2,3,4}^4|-|{2,3,4,5}^4|+|{2,3,4}^4|$, where the last term corrects for sequences that were subtracted twice.

@Karl Indeed, that can also be expressed as the complementary form PIE formulation.

@CalvinLin If i am understaing better then $\max(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=5$ and $\min(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=2$ will be $(5^4-4^4)-(4^4-3^4)-(3^4-2^4)=129$?

@Karl you can provide solution using P.I.E if it is possible for you so i can understand tihs concept better

@mathophole The idea is to start with all $5^4$ tuples in ${1,2,3,4,5}^4$ and then subtract the invalid ones. Let $A$ be the set of tuples that don't have a $1$ and let $B$ be the set of tuples that don't have a $5$. The set of invalid tuples is $A\cup B$, so count them using PIE.

@mathophile No to "max of 5 and min of 2". Can you elaborate on what those terms represent, and how they give us the desired outcome?

using method by @Karl I obtained $|{2,3,4,5}^4|-|{2,3,4}^4|-|{3,4,5}^4|+|{3,4}^4|=110$

@mathophile Right, that should yield $4^4 - 3^4 - 3^4 + 2^4$. It is the same as "max of 4 and min of 1" (establish the bijection by subtracting 1 from every term)
